# A smoother alternative to jQuery show() and hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page setup with a hidden column using the jQuery show() and hide() functions to slide the column in and out.

However it's kind of "clunky" and does not look very smooth when showing/hiding; in contrast I also have a section of the page using jquery UI accordion.  When switching between these sections the transition looks very nice and smooth...

Is there a better function than show()/hide() which looks as nice as the accordion does? (maybe the "easing" parameter can be used in the show/hide functions, but i'm not sure how to use this properly?)

Comment: Are you animating table rows?

Comment: You can also try `animate` changing the width to `0px` to hide and something like `100%` to show..

Answer (score 5):

I guess you will want to use [jQuery.fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [jQuery.fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Comment: Or possibly slideIn / slideOut.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but instead of sliding the column in/out of viability the fadeIn/fadeOut functions suddenly jump the column width to 100% then fade it in, which is not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Also look at [jQuery.slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).

Comment: Thank, i've tried this, but slideToggle is also chunky/jumpy the same as the show/hide functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of JQuery UI's animation. I have the same problem when trying to animate my show()/hide()... the result is choppy. I ended up using [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/) for most of my animations simply because it provides smoother animations and more configurable than what JQuery UI provides. Scriptaculous can do what JQuery provides, plus more.

Answer (score 0):

you could use FadeOut() FadeIn() or slideDown slideUp . Make the duration is "slow" or in time

For more information: [Sliding effect](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/)

Here is another way by using animate()
http://www.vietanime.net/

the code example here:

```
// SLIDE FOOTER MENU 
    $('#footer-menu > li').hover(
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('a',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'bottom':'-45px'
                }, 300);
            $('i',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'top':'-10px'
                }, 700);
        },
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('a',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'bottom':'-145px'
                }, 300);
            $('i',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'top':'50px'
                }, 400);
        }
    );
```

and the html here:

```
<div id="bottom-slide-out-menu">

                    <ul id="footer-menu">
                            <li>
                                    <a>
                                            <i class="icon_about"></i>
                                            <span class="title">Search</span>
                                            <span class="description">Direct link, Mp3, Music, Video, Tutorials</span>
                                    </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                    <a>
                                            <i class="icon_work"></i>
                                            <span class="title">Listen</span>
                                            <span class="description">Mp3</span>
                                    </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                    <a href="archive.php">
                                            <i class="icon_help"></i>
                                            <span class="title">Archive</span>
                                            <span class="description">Direct Links Archive</span>
                                    </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                    <a href="search.php">
                                            <i class="icon_search"></i>
                                            <span class="title">Developer</span>
                                            <span class="description">Keywords, SEO, Website </span>
                                    </a>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
```

and some little css you could make it beautiful:

```
ul#footer-menu{

                            list-style:none;
                            position:absolute;
                            bottom:0px;
                            left:20px;
                            font-size:36px;
                            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                            font-weight: bold;
                            color:#999;
                            letter-spacing:-2px;
                    }
                    ul#footer-menu li{
                            float:left;
                            margin:0px 10px 0px 0px;
                    }
                    ul#footer-menu a{
                            cursor:pointer;
                            position:relative;
                            float:left;
                            bottom:-145px;
                            line-height:20px;
                            width:210px;
                    }
                    ul#footer-menu a:hover{
                            text-decoration: none;
                    }
```