# jQuery show target div not starting at 0% width and height (Update)

Tags: jquery, show

Sorry if this has been posted a million times, it's possible my search skills are failing me. I have a question that's probably something obvious and easy.

I have slide functionality on my website, which can be found here: http://jasenpeterson.com/12-Years/v4/

The slide functionality works well, but is there anyway to make it so that the div doesn't have to 'grow' from a height and width of 0% to 100%?

I'm probably doing a poor job of explaining my issue but if you look at the website and select 'synopsis' you should understand what I'm talking about.

Thanks in advance.

I'll continue to look for solutions and if I find oneI'll post back. Thanks again!

Here is my code if it helps:

`var $btns = $('.nav a'), $slides = $('.slides > .content');`

```
$btns.click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('active');
  $slides.eq($btns.index(this)).show('slow').siblings().hide('slow');
  return false;
});

$btns.first().click();
```

---------------Update

Hi all, I hope I'm not breaking any rules by updating my topic. After a little research it sounds like I should be using the animate function.

I've been tinkering around with animating the opacity, it works for the first page (fades in and out) but not for the other pages. I can see that the opacity is being set to 100 in the console..but it's not being displayed. Any ideas?

http://jasenpeterson.com/12-Years/v4/

`var $btns = $('.nav a'), $slides = $('.slides > .content');`

```
$btns.click(function(){
  //add 'active' class to active link
  $(this).addClass('active');
  //remove 'active' class from previous link
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('active');
  $slides.eq($btns.index(this)).animate( {"opacity": "1"}, "slow").siblings().animate( {"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
  return false;
});

//First link clicked on page load
$btns.first().click();
```

Comment: Where is the slide functionality on your website?

Comment: Hi Alien, it's possible I removed it when testing something. If you refresh you should see it. Actually, I think I'm using the wrong terminology. I'm referring to jquery 'show' and 'hide' it looks like it's sliding (kind of) which is why I said that. I updated the post to correct the mistake.

Comment: Why don't you like the div growing from 0 to 100%?

Comment: Hi phemios, it doesn't look that great from an aesthetic point of view (in my opinion). The transition that happens when you select pages without a background image is what I'm going for. I'd like it to look like that, accept with a BG image. Well the 'growth' effect happens with all the divs but it's not as obvious without a BG.

Comment: You should take a look to [A smoother alternative to jQuery show() and hide()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327862/a-smoother-alternative-to-jquery-show-and-hide). You might find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I got it.

`var $btns = $('.nav a'), $slides = $('.slides > .content');`

```
$btns.click(function(){
  //add 'active' class to active link
  $(this).addClass('active');
  //remove 'active' class from previous link
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('active');
  $slides.eq($btns.index(this)).animate( {"opacity": "1"}, "slow").siblings().animate( {"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
  siblings().hide('fast');
  return false;
});

//First link clicked on page load
$btns.first().click();
```